# Ubuntu 14.04 updated last night - HDMI video stopped working

Tags: 14.04, display, intel-graphics, hdmi

Ubuntu 14.04 with an integrated Intel graphics card that has worked for 6 months connected only to a Samsung TV via HDMI.

Software update ran last night, installed some new packages.  After rebooting, the computer will not recognize the HDMI TV connected to it - the only video device.  VNC & ssh was installed, so I connected that way fine.

One of my drives (non-boot /dev/sdb mapped to /home) was full - it is usually pretty full.  I cleaned out space and rebooted, no luck.

Did another apt-get update with no luck.

Verified that a new boot image in `/vmlinuz` and `/initrd.img` point to `/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-58-generic` created this evening and `...-56` was created this morning.

Used grub to boot from the previous version `...-51` created end of March with no luck.

Tried:

```
xrander --addmode 1920x1020 
xrander --output HDMI1 --mode --1920x1080
```

hung the computer.

Tried different HDMI cable and different HDMI port on the TV, no luck.

I have downloaded intel graphics package and could start building it from scratch (havent done kernel build in years), or have done a dd backup of the boot drive - could reinstall ubuntu on it... 14 or 16rc?

Output of `lshw` and `xrander`:

```
lshw   part
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff
 ioport:f000(size=64)

xrander
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 886mm x 498mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: This may be a silly suggestion, so forgive me if it is not helpful, but when I plug in HDMI to my laptop with intel integrated graphics, I have to open the Display settings application to get the HDMI monitor to be recognized.  Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes.  The monitor does not show up under system settings -> screen display, even after clicking on detect displays.   For the xrander above, the pc was connected to a VGA disply to avoid VNC lag.

Comment: Also tried to create a new mode - it also hangs the UI (not the whole computer)        cvt 1920 1080 60
  xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "1920x1080_60.00"
  xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"

Comment: Connected a macbook to the TV through HDMI - works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As with most other issues I have seen here - it was a bunch of random actions that fixed it.

1. Connected to VGA and HDMI - only VGA worked.
2. Created an installation USB for ubuntu 14.04 using "startup disk      creator" and left it in the USB.
3. Shutdown using the GUI.
4. Booted into BIOS and changed the boot order to have USB boot first
   (or so I thought).
5. Left the BIOS at Press Enter to Save & Close
6. Disconnected VGA cable
7. Pressed Enter... PC rebooted and HDMI worked - booted immediately into Ubuntu - not
   the live/install USB.
8. Removed the USB, rebooted and it still works!?!